# How to restrict users of a particular profile to edit personal information

Tags: permissions, setup

I want a particular profile not to update their phone or mobile number under personal information. How do I restrict that?

Comment: Are you talking about editing their Chatter profile details?

Comment: I am concerned about personal information

Answer (score 3):

You can use a validation rule on the User object to accomplish this. Here is an example:

```
AND(ISCHANGED( Email ), NOT(OR($Profile.Name = "System Administrator", $Profile.Name = "Profile X", $Profile.Name = "Profile Y" )))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. I was able to solve it using the answer above:

```
AND(ISCHANGED(Email), NOT(OR($Profile.Name = "System Administrator", $Profile.Name = "Profile X", $Profile.Name = "Profile Y" )))
```

But instead of allowing only admins to do the edit, I restricted the user profile:

```
AND(ISCHANGED(field),$Profile.Name = "UserProfileName")
```

Comment: Friendly note that the Profile Name can be updated without warning when it's referenced in a Validation Rule (_or other means_) and that this approach doesn't work in multi-lingual orgs (e.g. in English, "System Administrator" --> "Administrador del sistema" in Spanish). A custom permission here may be more scalable and prevent the need to change someone's profile should they ever need access to edit this field.